# Difference between ng-bind, ng-bind-html, ng-bind-html-unsafe in AngularJS?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ng-bind-html, ng-bind

I want to know difference between `ng-bind`, `ng-bind-html` and `ng-bind-html-unsafe`.

Also when I run below code, I am getting error which is as mentioned below :

Code :

```
 <%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
        pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
    <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
<title>HTML Injection Security in AngularJS</title>

<script type="text/javascript" src="/js/angular.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">

angular.module("myApp", []).controller("myController",function($scope)
{
    $scope.getValue = function()
    {
        return "<b>Hello World</b>";
    };
});

</script>

</head>
<body>

<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myController">
    <span ng-bind-html="getValue();"></span>
    <span>Normal Text</span>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Error :

> Error: [$sce:unsafe] Attempting to use an unsafe value in a safe context.
>       http://errors.angularjs.org/1.3.11/$sce/unsafe
>           at REGEX_STRING_REGEXP (https://www.angularapprj.com:4443/js/angular.js:63:12)
>           at htmlSanitizer (https://www.angularapprj.com:4443/js/angular.js:15053:13)
>           at getTrusted (https://www.angularapprj.com:4443/js/angular.js:15217:16)
>           at Object.$get.sce.(anonymous function) [as getTrustedHtml] (https://www.angularapprj.com:4443/js/angular.js:15897:16)
>           at Object.ngBindHtmlWatchAction [as fn] (https://www.angularapprj.com:4443/js/angular.js:20449:29)
>           at Scope.$get.Scope.$digest (https://www.angularapprj.com:4443/js/angular.js:14230:29)
>           at Scope.$get.Scope.$apply (https://www.angularapprj.com:4443/js/angular.js:14493:24)
>           at bootstrapApply (https://www.angularapprj.com:4443/js/angular.js:1449:15)
>           at Object.invoke (https://www.angularapprj.com:4443/js/angular.js:4182:17)
>           at doBootstrap (https://www.angularapprj.com:4443/js/angular.js:1447:14)

What does it mean? I know using declarative code within imperative code is not good practice, though I was just trying with `<b>Hello World</b>` in `ng-bind-html` directive.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After searching I got below information from https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/migration#ngbindhtmlunsafe-has-been-removed-and-replaced-by-ngbindhtml: In Angular version 1.3 they have migrated from ng-bind-html-unsafe to ng-bind-html, though one point of question is remaining,Why I am getting error which is mentioned in post ?

[image]